# SHELL: How do I use a or operator when defining a string

Tags: linux, shell, glob

This may not even be possible but Im writing my first shell script and I need to use a regexp type operator in my string (shown below)

```
FILES=tif2/name(45|79)*.pdf
```

Is this possible? Or would I just have to have two strings.

```
FILES=tif2/name45*.pdf
FILES=tif2/name79*.pdf
```

Comment: Brace expansion will do it. `{45,79}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives in the shell globbing syntax use a comma-separated list enclosed by semicolons.  Your example becomes:

```
FILES=tif2/name{45,79}*.pdf
```

There's [a pretty nice quick reference here](http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/glob.html) to the glob syntax supported by most shells.

For the more esoteric bash-specific glob syntax, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: Informative, but at least with bash, if one of the entries is missing, you would get "tif2/name79*.pdf" as a result rather than an expanded value.

Comment: @B Mitch: That can be controlled with the `nullglob` option, apparently.

Comment: @B Mitch: So did I... I still had the bash shell expansion reference open in another tab, so I went looking.  I was thinking that maybe if any of the words got expanded, they all would (even to nothing) but it turned out there's a relevant option.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, zsh, pdksh and ksh93, you can use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob   # Bash
setopt KSH_GLOB    # zsh
FILES=tif2/name@(45|79)*.pdf
```

The `@()` operator matches one of the patterns within which are separated by pipe characters.

Answer (score 0):

If your specific shell doesn't support such advanced globbing, you can always use `grep`:

```
FILES=`ls tif2/name[0-9][0-9]*.pdf|egrep "name(45|79)" | tr "\012" " "`
```

Comment: I think that'll end up with newlines between matches, instead of spaces between matches.  Not sure whether it matters in this particular case.

Comment: Don't forget the backticks.  I think stackoverflow may have eaten them.  Edit: NM, looks like you got them now.

Comment: The backticks make the `tr` unnecessary. However, you need a `-1` option to the `ls` command to ensure it doesn't print more than one filename on a line.  Also, this will fail horribly on names containing whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the shell to ignore any special characters in the string, enclose it with single quotes.

`FILES='tif2/name(45|79)*.pdf'`